# Is there any function to create pairing of values from columns in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe, data-science

I have to make the pairing of values in particular column like 3 2 2 4 2 2 to [3,2][2,2][2,4][4,2][2,2] in whole of the data set.

Expected output

[[3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 2], [2, 2]] Every row in separate columns like Pair 1 , Pair 2 ,Pair 3 ....

content = pd.read_csv('temp2.csv')

df = ([content], columns=['V2','V3','V4','V5','V6','V7'])
def get_pairs(x):
    arr = x.split(' ')
    return list(map(list, zip(arr,arr[1:])))

df['pairs'] = df.applymap(get_pairs)
df

Comment: Please share the code you have tried.

Comment: content = pd.read_csv('temp2.csv')

df = ([content], columns=['V2','V3','V4','V5','V6','V7']) def get_pairs(x): arr = x.split(' ') return list(map(list, zip(arr,arr[1:])))

df['pairs'] = df.applymap(get_pairs) df

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can use list comprehension and `zip`:

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame([3, 2, 2, 4, 2, 2], columns=['col1'])

[[x, y] for x, y in zip(df.loc[:, 'col1'], df.loc[1:, 'col1'])]
```

or alternatively using `map` and `list` constructor:

```
list(map(list, zip(df.loc[:, 'col1'], df.loc[1:, 'col1'])))
```

[out]

```
[[3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 2], [2, 2]]
```

---

Or if this is how your data is structured you could use [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) with your own function:

```
# Setup
df = pd.DataFrame(['3 2 2 4 2 2', '1 2 3 4 5 6'], columns=['col1'])

#           col1
# 0  3 2 2 4 2 2
# 1  1 2 3 4 5 6

def get_pairs(x):
    arr = x.split(' ')
    return list(map(list, zip(arr, arr[1:])))

df['pairs'] = df.applymap(get_pairs)
```

[out]

```
          col1                                     pairs
0  3 2 2 4 2 2  [[3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 2], [2, 2]]
1  1 2 3 4 5 6  [[1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6]]
```

Comment: Is it possible with for loop with n rows

Comment: @P_data not sure I understand the question?

Comment: 6 columns with 3 millions rows data set how to iterate with it do it have any function

Comment: can you add a small representative example of your dataframe, with expected output to your question?

Comment: Output I want the paired values  
[[3, 2], [2, 2], [2, 4], [4, 2], [2, 2]] From each row to a new column separately

Comment: Please check out the guidelines for [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @P_data, can you check the update...? is this along the lines you mean?

Comment: @P_data glad it helped :)

Comment: i am getting problem in reading the data from my dataframe which is in name content

def get_pairs(x):
    arr = x.split(' ')
    return list(map(list, zip(arr,arr[1:])))

new_content['pairs'] = new_Content.applymap(get_pairs)
content = reading the file in it 
new_content = (content.columns)